# Can I display a million record in a html table in one go?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently creating a web-based system that would have a millions of data after some years (3 years = 1 million record, just guessing).

Now I have a webpage where I display all records in a html table dynamically.

If the time comes **can it display these amount of data**?
What are the things I need to consider?

What about hardware requirements (for the server probably)?

- The set up would be a LAN set up to be use by 7 users simultaneously.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a my php code:
[my php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFmGM.jpg)

and this is the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKoEO.jpg)

Comment: This question is hard to answer as nobody can know what _"a millions of data"_ or _"1 million record"_ is. Please add some example code.

Comment: I added my php code and the result.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your browser will crash if you display this inside of a table or list.

The only way i see is to lazy load and keep the DOM as small as possible while scrolling through.

Why do you want to display one million records?

Comment: I want to retrieve all the data and store it inside the html table so that it could easily search items. I have a responsive and paginated table will that help the problem or not?

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer, I am the maintainer)
Wrote a grid for this purpose. It will load any amount of rows and render the rows within 2ms of initializing the grid. Scrolls 60fps even on older laptops. The only limit is how much RAM you have, but I have loaded 2m rows into a m2 8gb laptop

Demo:
https://fast-grid.vercel.app/
Github:
https://github.com/gabrielpetersson/fast-grid

Comment: Can you give a brief about How to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Possible but browser will possibly crash.
Best approach is to have a pagination that will display like, 100 per page maybe, and have a search function.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: well my table is paginated, it will only show 10 entries by default but my code retrieves all the data and store it inside the html table. will that work?

Comment: what kind of pagination? are you using something like datatable? if yes, it only hides the data inside the pages but still loads all of your data, what you might need is a pagination using php and uses the Mysql limit clause.
check this link for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Answer (score 0):

it's not a human readable ,
you can get all data from the database is possible and saved it in an array 
then make search in array and get the result what you want

Answer (score 0):

I am using 1 million cells (not rows) in a plain HTML table.

It takes some time do download the data and some more to render it. But if you really need it you can display it. I don't see a production use case. I only display it to spot inconsistent data. So, not going to prod.

There are multiple component libraries to handle continuous scroll.